# Issue with a loop using Arduino classes

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a problem trying to use classes in Arduino and my particular problem is that my code won't work as i have thought. I'll explain:

I made a library that allows me to control a series of LEDs making them blink, and I'd like to repeat them as many times as programmed. However, I've found a problem with it: when I run the code the cycle will repeat just once and it won't blink all of the LEDs again, as the code is supposed to do. This is the code:

Header

```
#ifndef Cluster_h
#define Cluster_h

#include "Storm.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

class Cluster{
    public:
        Cluster(int pin[]);
        void lightning(unsigned long g_glag[]);
    private:
        unsigned long currentmillis,prevmillis,g_flag[];
        int counter,u_flag;
        Storm* _led;
};



#endif
```

CPP file

```
#include <Cluster.h>

Cluster::Cluster(int pin[]){
    Storm led[7]={Storm(pin[0]),Storm(pin[1]),Storm(pin[2]),Storm(pin[3]),Storm(pin[4]),Storm(pin[5]),Storm(pin[6])};
    _led=led;
    prevmillis=0;
    counter=0;
}

void Cluster::lightning(unsigned long g_flag[]){


    if(counter<=5){  
        currentmillis=millis();

        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[0]){
            _led[0].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[1]){
            _led[1].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[2]){
            _led[2].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[3]){
            _led[3].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[4]){
            _led[4].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[5]){
            _led[5].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[6]){
            prevmillis=currentmillis;
            counter=counter+1;
        }

    }
}
```

The `blinkled` function from the `Storm` class is imported from the header file and what this function does is blinking a particular LED (this is already defined). With this code I would expect that the blinking sequence would repeat for 5 times but as I mentioned at the beginning it will blink all the LEDs just once. I have not found what could be wrong with the code, if you could help me that would be awesome.

I appreciate your time, I'll also put the code in the implementation part, just in case.

```
#include <Cluster.h>

int p[7]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
unsigned long gf[7]={50,70,110,150,220,240,1000};
Cluster cluster(p);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  cluster.lightning(gf);
}
```

Comment: Do you want all the led to blink 5 times?

Comment: C tag removed as not a C question.  @INME, Review the tags needed for your post.

Comment: Hi there, thakns for your answer. The problem still persists. I have an idea but i don't know if it will work... what about destroying those created objects when the cycle completes? i don't know how to use that destructor, if you also know how to use it i would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes in deed, i want them to blink 5 times

Comment: Why do you insist on class? Your result can be easily achieved by using `static` variables inside `loop()` with function that processes it without oop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting `prevmillis`

Change your function

```
void Cluster::lightning(unsigned long g_flag[]){

    static unsigned long prevmillis=millis();
    if(counter<=5){  
        currentmillis=millis();

        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[0]){
            _led[0].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[1]){
            _led[1].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[2]){
            _led[2].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[3]){
            _led[3].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[4]){
            _led[4].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[5]){
            _led[5].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[6]){
            prevmillis=currentmillis;
            counter=counter+1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by dosen't worj? Do you get same output?

Comment: It works! im sorry, i had trouble in my Storm class, i just realized and now it works fine. Sorry for the time wasted on my question, thanks for the answers!